# Java socket between 2 hosts on different subnets

Tags: java, web-services, sockets, subnet

In Java, we can open a ServerSocket with *new ServerSocket(port)*, and connect to it with new *Socket(server_adress",port)*; 
But how to connect, if server is in a different network, while both networks are behind a NAT.

I know that there must be a solution. Skype and other applications already found it.

Any ideas ?

Regards, Andrew.

Comment: Are you actually having a problem if server and client are in different subnets or are you just assuming there's a problem?  Show us some code you have tried and perhaps we can help you to resolve whatever problem you're having?

Comment: It doesn't matter wether the server and the client are on different subnets. What is the problem you are having?

Comment: this is less of a java question than a networking question really. you should give some more detail on the topology of your network (routers, NAT, IP addresses, ...)

Comment: There's 2 solutions, 1. Set up port forwarding in your router. 2. Do hole punching, like Skype does (expect to spend the better part of the year implementing this in a general fashion).

Answer (score 1):

For a list of all the methods, some of which are used by Skype, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal

Once you've picked a method, use Google to search for a Java implementation of that method.  (Or follow the links from that wiki page, e.g. http://jstun.javawi.de/ )